# Simple jQuery lightbox is not working on Rails app. Help please?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb, sass

I wanted to ask why my Lightbox isn't working.  In my .html.erb file, I have:

```
<a href="http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/patel-neil1-300x200.jpg?7794fe" class="thumbnail lightbox">
<img src="http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/patel-neil1-300x200.jpg?7794fe" alt="">
</a>
```

And in my .css.scss file I have:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: black url(loader.gif) no-repeat scroll center center;
}

#lightbox {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Finally, for my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#toggleButton').click(function() {
        if ($('#experiment').is(':visible')) {
            $('#experiment').hide();
        } else {
            $('#experiment').show();
        }
    });

    alert('working!');

    $('a.lightbox').click(function(e) {
        // hide scrollbars!
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');

        $('<div id="overlay"></div>')
            .css('top', $(document).scrollTop())
            .css('opacity', '0')
            .animate({'opacity': '0.5'}, 'slow')
            .appendTo('body');

        $('<div id="lightbox"></div>')
            .hide()
            .appendTo('body');

        $('<img>')
            .attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
            .load(function() {
                positionLightboxImage();
            })
            .click(function() {
                removeLightbox();
            })
            .appendto('#lightbox');

        return false;
    });

    function positionLightboxImage() {
        var top = ($(window).height() - $('#lightbox').height()) / 2;
        var left = ($(window).width() - $('#lightbox').width()) / 2;
    $('#lightbox')
        .css({
            'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
            'left': left
        })
        .fadeIn();  
    }

    function removeLightbox() {
        $('#overlay, #lightbox')
            .fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(this).remove();
                $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto'); // show scrollbars!
            });
    }

});
```

I am using the Chrome web inspector to debug errors in the Javascript, and now I'm not throwing any at all, so I don't see what's wrong here?  Especially since the jQuery alert I put in DOES actually pop up, and the hide functionality works... I'm stumped as to what the corrective path for my lightbox would be. :\  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

[image]

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you actual problem is?  That graphic is just your way of showing the JS you are including, correct?  So what exactly is going wrong with your code?  How is it failing?

Comment: Right now, the lightbox doesn't seem to be working at all.  When I click on a thumbnail image enclosed within the <a> tag, the lightbox doesn't seem to activate.

Comment: You are not selecting the image tag properly. Remove the **<** and **>**. Should be '$("img")'. Also, since you wrapped the image in the _a_ tag make sure you are selecting the correct image. Cache the result of '$("img")' and see what you get. Hope that helps.

Comment: var $image = $('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')); then just console.log($image); See if that returns anything...

Comment: Ignore my previous response. I see what you're trying to do. But the image is not getting appended, there is a spelling error .appendto('#lightbox'); capital t in "appendTo"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your a little weak on your jquery

For example,  where you write this:

```
$('<div id="overlay"></div>')
```

The proper way to do it is probably

```
$('#overlay')
```

Try redoing as above and see what happens

Comment: do agree with RadBrad, for me in my case, the last solution u might do can jz alert in how your lightbox flow,there shld be a place that occurs errors since your code is not too long.

Comment: RadBrad that didn't work for me.  I thought that the syntax to create new elements on the fly is the way I did it?  And that only when you are selecting it after creation that you use the selector method...?

Comment: Didn't even think of that?  I've never added elements like that so I didn't recognize what you were doing.  Are you sure that syntax works,  I've just never seen it done that way.